# SSAS Tabular Model: Difference between calculated table and DAX

Tags: ssas, dax, azure-analysis-services

Just wondering if anyone had encounter this situation, that calculated table returns no row, but when evaluating the DAX it returns correct result.

In one of my tabular models, I created several summarized tables to improve query performance. The summarized table linked to the project table by project ID. I also have a row level security applied on project table.

For some reasons, I was told the report does not work. When I use SSMS to browse the tabular model via user's account, I found that if I evaluate the table directly it returns no row, e.g.

```
evaluate my_summarized_table
```

But, if I evaluate the formula directly it returns correct result, e.g.

```
evaluate Filter(Summarize(mytable, 'Project'[Project Id]...))
```

I tried to use SQL Profiler and $system.Discover_Sessions but could not figure out what is the difference between the calculated table and the raw DAX query.

Had anyone have this situation before? What could be the possible reason for that?